# How does one show that the residue of the first derivative of a holomorphic function is zero in its singularity?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

I've got a holomorphic function $f:\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ and I want to show that $$res_{0}f'=0$$

Comment: for example, the integral on a circle around zero of $f'$ is zero, while it is also a multiple of the residue at zero, or use the Laurent series of $f$ and differentiate term by term and see that there is no $1/z$ term in the derivative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying the definition of Residue as the -1'th Laurent series coefficient: $$\operatorname{Res}(f';0)=a_{-1}=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{\gamma}\,\frac{f'(z)}{(z-c)^{-1+1}}\,dz = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{\gamma}\,f'(z)\,dz .$$

And $f'$ has a primitive along all of $\gamma$ so this integral is $0$.